# Wrapping Software Mentions in XML

Tags: python, xml, xslt, beautifulsoup, elementtree

I have an xml file with mentions of software inside of `<p>` tags. I would like to create a script to catch those sofwtares and wrapp them in a some kind of tag (like `<software>`) just to be able to identify them after.

so far i have tried using :

- xmltree
- beautifull soup
- lxml
- converting the xml to json

The main issue is that my mentions are usually located inside a `<p>` tag that has some `<ref>`tags.
Here is an example of one the `<p>` tags and the mention of the software "MODELLER"(I truncated it because the `<p>` can be up to 3 or 4 time bigger):

```xml
<p> The reliability of the model structure was tested using the ENERGY commands of MODELLER <ref type="bibr" target="#b45">(Sali and Blundell, 1993)</ref>. The modelled structures were also validated using the program PROSA <ref type="bibr" target="#b54">(Wiederstein and Sippl, 2007)</ref>.</p>
```

the expected result :

```xml
<p> The reliability of the model structure was tested using the ENERGY commands of <software>MODELLER</software> <ref type="bibr" target="#b45">(Sali and Blundell, 1993)</ref>. The modelled structures were also validated using the program PROSA <ref type="bibr" target="#b54">(Wiederstein and Sippl, 2007)</ref>.</p>
```

A simple search and replace operation won't work as I'm trying to find a specific mention of the software. To be precise I have a JSON with every mentions found in the xml. In the JSON every mentions is linked with a the context. So for the entry for MODELLER in the json would be linked to this context : "The reliability of the model structure was tested using the ENERGY commands of MODELLER (Sali and Blundell, 1993)."(the context contains the sentence with the software and without any sub-child).

an example of the JSON:

```json
{
            "type": "software",
            "software-type": "software",
            "software-name":
            {
                "rawForm": "MODELLER",
                "normalizedForm": "MODELLER",
                "offsetStart": 79,
                "offsetEnd": 87,
                "boundingBoxes":
                [
                    {
                        "p": 4,
                        "x": 495.722,
                        "y": 320.344,
                        "w": 53.9323,
                        "h": 8.0517
                    }
                ]
            },
            "context": "The reliability of the model structure was tested using the ENERGY commands of MODELLER (Sali and Blundell, 1993)."
}
```

The best script that I made would be this one :

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '<root><p>hello, this is a test sentence with a <ref type="table" target="tab_0">reference_1</ref>, my software is MOD and here is another <ref type="table" target="tab_0">reference_2</ref> and some more text</p></root>'
root = ET.fromstring(xml)

p = root.find('p')
p_string = "".join(p.itertext())

software = 'MOD'

p_str_wo_child = str(p.text)

sub_tags_list = []
list_p = list(p)
p_software_index= p_str_wo_child.find(software)
for elm in list_p:
    index = p_string.find(elm.text)
    print(elm.tail)
    if index != -1:
        sub_tags_list.append([elm.tag, elm.text, elm.tail, index])
        p_string = p_string.replace(elm.text, '', 1)
    p_str_wo_child += str(elm.tail)
    p.remove(elm)

sub_tags_list = sorted(sub_tags_list, key=lambda x: x[3])
print(sub_tags_list)
p_software_index= p_str_wo_child.find(software)

if p_software_index:

    sub_tags_list.append(["software", software, False,p_software_index])
    sub_tags_list = sorted(sub_tags_list, key=lambda x: x[3])
    print(sub_tags_list)
    for tag_name, tag_content, tail ,index in sub_tags_list:
        tag = ET.Element(tag_name)
        tag.text = tag_content
        if tail == False:
            index_software = last_tail.find(software)
            tag.tail = last_tail[index_software:].replace(software,'')
            print(tag.tail)
        else:
            if tail.find(software):
                tag.tail = tail[:tail.find(software)].replace(software, '')
                last_tail = tail
            else:
                tag.tail = tail
                last_tail = tail
        p.append(tag)

modified_xml = ET.tostring(root, encoding='unicode')

print(modified_xml)
```

Comment: Yes, the aim is to wrap the mention of a software whitout modifying the <p> tag.

Comment: How can one identify the substring `MODELLER` as being "software"? And how is it different from the substring `PROSA` which isn't tagged as such in your expected result?

Comment: a simple search and replace operation won't work as I'm trying to find a specific mention of the software. To be precise i have a JSON with every mentions found in the xml. In the JSON every mentions is linked with a the context. So for the entry for MODELLER in the json would  be linked to this context : "The reliability of the model structure was tested using the ENERGY commands of MODELLER (Sali and Blundell, 1993)."(the context will retrieve the sentence with the software and without any sub-child).

Comment: Please add a sample of the JSON to the question.

Comment: As for the identification of the software, we have a JSON obtained from an IA. PROSA is indeed another software mentions, but I think if i will wrap every software one by one.

Comment: How does the JSON look exactly, is it an array of strings of those quotes, an object of string key/string quote pairs (e.g. `{ "MODELLER" : "The reliability of the model structure was tested using the ENERGY commands of MODELLER (Sali and Blundell, 1993)."}`?

Comment: In the text you gave the context as `"The reliability of the model structure was tested using the ENERGY commands of MODELLER (Sali and Blundell, 1993)."`, in the JSON the context is kind of truncated `"The reliability of the model structure was tested using the ENERGY commands of k (Sali and Blundell, 1993)."` (i.e. the word `MODELLER` doesn't appear).

Comment: thank's this is my mistake i changed the json when editing my issue (i'm putting back the software)

Answer (score 1):

I might try to tackle this using XSLT 3 (and [saxonche](https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/) from PyPi) as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:iterate select="$json-doc?*[?type = 'software']">
      <xsl:param name="p" select="."/>
      <xsl:on-completion select="$p"/>
      <xsl:if test="contains($p, ?context)">
        <xsl:variable name="transformed-p" as="element(p)">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$p" mode="process">
            <xsl:with-param name="software" select="." tunnel="yes"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:next-iteration>
          <xsl:with-param name="p" select="$transformed-p"/>
        </xsl:next-iteration>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:iterate>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode name="process" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template mode="process" match="p//text()">
    <xsl:param name="software" tunnel="yes" as="map(*)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($software?context, .) and contains(., $software?software-name?normalizedForm)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., $software?software-name?normalizedForm)" mode="wrap"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:next-match/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="wrap" match="*:match">
    <software>{.}</software>
  </xsl:template>
  

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:param name="json-doc" select="json-doc('your-json-file.json')"/>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Example fiddle](https://saxonc-xmlworkbench.azurewebsites.net/?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22p%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aiterate%20select%3D%22%24json-doc%3F*%5B%3Ftype%20%3D%20%27software%27%5D%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22p%22%20select%3D%22.%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aon-completion%20select%3D%22%24p%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aif%20test%3D%22contains%28%24p%2C%20%3Fcontext%29%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22transformed-p%22%20as%3D%22element%28p%29%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%24p%22%20mode%3D%22process%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Awith-param%20name%3D%22software%22%20select%3D%22.%22%20tunnel%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aapply-templates%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-iteration%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Awith-param%20name%3D%22p%22%20select%3D%22%24transformed-p%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Anext-iteration%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aif%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aiterate%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20name%3D%22process%22%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20mode%3D%22process%22%20match%3D%22p%2F%2Ftext%28%29%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22software%22%20tunnel%3D%22yes%22%20as%3D%22map%28*%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Achoose%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Awhen%20test%3D%22contains%28%24software%3Fcontext%2C%20.%29%20and%20contains%28.%2C%20%24software%3Fsoftware-name%3FnormalizedForm%29%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22analyze-string%28.%2C%20%24software%3Fsoftware-name%3FnormalizedForm%29%22%20mode%3D%22wrap%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Awhen%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Achoose%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20mode%3D%22wrap%22%20match%3D%22*%3Amatch%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Csoftware%3E%7B.%7D%3C%2Fsoftware%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20indent%3D%22no%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22json-doc%22%20select%3D%22parse-json%28%24json-data%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22json-data%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22%20expand-text%3D%22no%22%3E%5B%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22software%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22software-type%22%3A%20%22software%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22software-name%22%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22rawForm%22%3A%20%22MODELLER%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22normalizedForm%22%3A%20%22MODELLER%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22offsetStart%22%3A%2079%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22offsetEnd%22%3A%2087%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22boundingBoxes%22%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22p%22%3A%204%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22x%22%3A%20495.722%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22y%22%3A%20320.344%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22w%22%3A%2053.9323%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22h%22%3A%208.0517%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22context%22%3A%20%22The%20reliability%20of%20the%20model%20structure%20was%20tested%20using%20the%20ENERGY%20commands%20of%20MODELLER%20%28Sali%20and%20Blundell%2C%201993%29.%22%0A%7D%20%20%0A%20%20%5D%3C%2Fxsl%3Aparam%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3Cp%3EThe%20reliability%20of%20the%20model%20structure%20was%20tested%20using%20the%20ENERGY%20commands%20of%20MODELLER%20%3Cref%20type%3D%22bibr%22%20target%3D%22%23b45%22%3E%28Sali%20and%20Blundell%2C%201993%29%3C%2Fref%3E.%20The%20modelled%20structures%20were%20also%20validated%20using%20the%20program%20PROSA%20%3Cref%20type%3D%22bibr%22%20target%3D%22%23b54%22%3E%28Wiederstein%20and%20Sippl%2C%202007%29%3C%2Fref%3E.%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML). There the JSON data is inlined but you can of course read it from a file.